# FLTK: how to put graphical object in foreground?

Tags: c++, graphics, fltk

I have two draggable objects inside a window: the one containing the black square is in background while the one containing the red square is in the foreground.

[image: Image Not Found]

This layout is due to the order in which they are drawn. I would like to  have in the foreground the one that I am currently dragging: for example, if I drag the box with the black square I want it on the foreground. Once I dropped it, it should remain in the foreground. If I drag the red one I want it to be in the foreground while the black one goes in the background.

I tried to check the documentation of FLTK 1.3.5 about [clipping](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/drawing.html#ssect_Clipping) but I did not find anything useful (at least, for what I can understand). Is there any way to achieve what I'd want?

The code (ispired by the one [here](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#DraggableBoxes)) is listed below.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Scroll.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Pixmap.H>
#include <iostream>

static char *box1_xpm[] = {                       // XPM
"20 20 2 1",
"  c #000000",
"# c None",
"####################",
"####################",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"####################",
"####################"
};

static char *box2_xpm[] = {                       // XPM
"20 20 2 1",
"  c #FF0000",
"# c None",
"####################",
"####################",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"#                  #",
"####################",
"####################"
};

Fl_Double_Window *G_win    = NULL;
Fl_Scroll        *G_scroll = NULL;
static Fl_Pixmap  G_box1(box1_xpm);
static Fl_Pixmap  G_box2(box2_xpm);

#define BOXWIDTH  50
#define BOXHEIGHT 50

// A 'MOVABLE' BOX
class Box : public Fl_Box {
protected:
    int handle(int e) {
        static int offset[2] = { 0, 0 };
        int ret = Fl_Box::handle(e);
        switch ( e ) {
            case FL_PUSH:
                offset[0] = x() - Fl::event_x();    // save where user clicked for dragging
                offset[1] = y() - Fl::event_y();
                return(1);
            case FL_RELEASE:
                return(1);
            case FL_DRAG:
                position(offset[0]+Fl::event_x(), offset[1]+Fl::event_y());     // handle dragging
                G_win->redraw();
                return(1);
        }
        return(ret);
    }
public:
    Box(int X, int Y, int idx) : Fl_Box(X,Y,BOXWIDTH,BOXHEIGHT,0) {
        idx>0? image(G_box1):image(G_box2);
        box(FL_UP_BOX);
        color(FL_GRAY);
    }
};

/// MAIN
int main() {
    G_win = new Fl_Double_Window(200,200);
    new Box(20,BOXHEIGHT,2);
    new Box(20+BOXWIDTH,BOXHEIGHT,0);
    G_win->resizable(G_win);
    G_win->show();
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets get drawn in the order in which they appear in the child() list of the parent.  The trick is to ensure the widget that is dragged is the last one drawn.  Change the push case as follows

```
            case FL_PUSH:
                {
                    offset[0] = x() - Fl::event_x();    // save where user clicked for dragging
                    offset[1] = y() - Fl::event_y();

                    // Do we need to rearrange?
                    int last_ix = G_win->children() - 1;
                    Box* last = (Box*)G_win->child(last_ix);
                    if (last != this)
                    {
                        // Widgets get drawn in the order in which they were inserted.
                        // Remove this widget from the parent
                        G_win->remove(this);
                        // Re-add it at the bottom of the list
                        G_win->add(this);
                    }
                }
                return(1);
```

Comment: It works as a charm, thanks. It is perfect also in case there are more than 2 widgets.

Comment: One more improvement - the offset does not need to be static - it can be declared as member variables.

Comment: Thanks, I did not have a careful look at the rest of the code, I focused on the foreground/background issue.